# How can I italicize the resulting text from an Entry widget in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry, text-formatting, italic

So an Entry widget's text can be retrieved using the `.get` method but my question is: 
Can you italicize the text that `.get` receives from the widget?

Adding the `font` parameter to the Entry only changes the text displayed in the Entry and not its actual output that `.get` gives you, so I'm at a loss.

What I'm actually trying to accomplish by doing this is italicizing only a certain part/string of the text of an Entry field while keeping the other parts of the text unitalicized, so if you have any tips for doing that instead, I'd appreciate the help!

Thanks in advance for the advice!

Comment: Try [`tk_html_widgets`](https://github.com/paolo-gurisatti/tk_html_widgets).

Answer (score 1):

> What I'm actually trying to accomplish by doing this is italicizing only a certain part/string of the text of an Entry field while keeping the other parts of the text unitalicized,

That is impossible. The Entry widget can only display text in a single font.

If you want to have multiple fonts, you will need to use either a Text or Canvas widget, with the Text widget being the easiest solution.

Comment: Thank you for the advice! I'll try implementing a Text widget instead